# Group Chat using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am very new to phonegap and I just want to know that , Is it possible to create Group Chat Mobile application in phonegap?? If yes then please provide some useful material..

Thank You,
Ronak Shah

Comment: The format for this site works much better when you've researched your question before hand and attempted to come up with a solution to the issue.  The idea here is to ask focused questions on specific issues in the course of development.  If your question doesn't fit this format, other forums may be of more use to you.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a good place to start looking](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/index.html). It is probably better to try something yourself first and come up with specific questions before asking other people to do your research.